# Sum multiple 2-way lookup values in one equation

Tags: google-sheets, formula, array-formulas

I've conquered a 2-way lookup for one Y axis and one X axis value using

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Y_AXIS_VALUE_ARRAY = Y_LOOKUP_VALUE)*(X_AXIS_VALUE_ARRAY = X_LOOKUP_VALUE), LOOKUP_ARRAY)
```

[image]

However what if I had multiple Y_LOOKUP values and multiple X_LOOKUP values and wanted to sum the results of all of them in one equation is this possible.
The example below shows what I'm after in this example the formula should return 105.78 (80.45 + 25.33).

[image]

The formula mentioned above when used to where X/Y Lookup values are an array of values returns Error
Array arguments to MULTIPLY are of different size.

Here is my test google sheet: https://docs.google.com/a/rentping.com/spreadsheets/d/1GWQHAclo19f1VxLBixI4eyKJDN1QRk6SzXKJDWj6ZaE/edit?usp=sharing

The "Test" sheet contains the interface where X/Y Look up values are selected, and the "Items" sheet contains the table that is being referenced.
Columns L, M, N, O are where the selection is made and Column K is where the formula goes.  As you can see when only ONE column has a selection the formula accurately gets the value, but as soon as a second value is selected in the those columns the formula breaks down.

Answer (score 1):

An easier way to perform double lookup is to use `filter` twice: for rows and for columns.  The wrapper `iferror` suppresses output when nothing is found.

```
=iferror(filter(filter(Items!A:Z, Items!A:A = L2), Items!A1:Z1 = L3))
```

With 4 columns to choose from, I'd go with

```
=iferror(filter(filter(Items!A:Z, Items!A:A = L2), Items!A1:Z1 = L3)) 
+iferror(filter(filter(Items!A:Z, Items!A:A = M2), Items!A1:Z1 = M3)) 
+iferror(filter(filter(Items!A:Z, Items!A:A = N2), Items!A1:Z1 = N3))
+iferror(filter(filter(Items!A:Z, Items!A:A = O2), Items!A1:Z1 = O3))
```

Alternatively, have additional hidden columns with lookups (one hidden column for each input column), and then column K can be a simple `sum` over hidden columns.

Comment: thanks for your answer!  I should have been more clear in my question.  While your answer does solve there problem (and of form of which I've ultimately implemented), what I'm looking for is a dynamic formula that will work with any number of columns...similar to the sumproduct formula mentioned above.

Comment: I don't think there is one.

Comment: That's what I figured, but thought it was worth asking.